# Formas de guardar la salida de un comando en una variable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, centos

Dos dudas, quizá simples y muy sencillas:

1 - Hace poco empecé a trabajar con bash y desde el principio me trabajado con el **$(comando)** para guardar las salidas de comandos, pero me he topado con ésta sintaxis: **`comando`**, en la mayoria de los blogs y pdf que he leído se usa la primera, incluso hacen mención que la forma correcta es esa pero la segunda forma veo que hace exactamente lo mismo, entonces ¿Cuál es la diferencia de usar la primera y segunda forma?

2 - ¿Cual es el proposito de los signos **{}** para imprimir una variable ya que sin ellas **echo "$ls_1"** o con ellas **echo "${ls_1}"** se muestra de igual forma la salida del comando?

```
ls_1=`ls -ltrh | grep bash`
echo "$ls_1"
echo "--------------------"
echo "${ls_1}"
echo "--------------------"

echo "********************"
ls_2=$(ls -ltrh | grep bash)
echo "$ls_2"
echo "--------------------"
echo "${ls_2}"
echo "--------------------"
```

De antemano gracias por las aclaraciones.

> PD: No me den manita abajo jejeje, igual son dudas sencillas pero son
>   dudas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como `man 1 bash` indica.

#### Respecto a tu primera pregunta

> **Command Substitution**
>
> ```
> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command name.  
> There are two forms:
>     $(command)
> or
>     `command`
> (...)
> When  the  old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal
> meaning except when followed by $, `, or \.  The first backquote not preceded by a backslash 
> terminates the command substitution.  When using the $(command) form, all characters between 
> the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.
> Command substitutions may be nested.  To nest when using the backquoted form, escape the 
> inner backquotes with backslashes.
> ```

Ambas son muy semejantes, se utilizan para la misma función, pero tienen pequeñas diferencias.

Respecto a las ejecuciones anidadas, como se indica, para anidar usando las *backquotes*, tienes que escaparlas.

```
$ echo `echo \`echo hola\``  # En este ejemplo escapamos.
hola
$ echo $(echo $(echo hola))  # En ese ejemplo no.
hola
```

Respecto a como cambia de significado el backslash pongo un ejemplo.

```
$ echo `echo \\$hola`  #  Aqui es necesario poner otro "\" frente al "\" para que sea tratado
                       #+ de forma especial y escape el signo "$".
$hola
$ echo $(echo \$hola)  #  En este caso no hay problema, "\" escapa al signo "$"
$hola
```

Referente a los escapes, como te podrás haber dado cuenta, es problemático anidar y escapar con la sintaxis del backquote.

```
$ echo $(echo \`hola)
`hola
$ echo `echo \\\`hola `  # Esto es insano
`hola
```

Otros ejemplos son:

```
$ echo "`echo \"hola\"`"
hola
$ echo `echo \"hola\"`     # Aqui si muestra las comillas dobles
"hola"
$ echo "`echo \\"hola\\"`" # Pero aqui, entrecomillado, hay que escapar el backslash
"hola"
$ echo $(echo \"hola\")    # En cambio, es mas comodo tratar con la sintaxis
"hola"                     # de $()
$ echo "$(echo \"hola\")"  
"hola"
```

#### Respecto a tu segunda pregunta

En el mismo `man 1 bash`

Hay un apartado sobre *Parameter expansion*

```
${parameter}
    The  value  of  parameter is substituted.  The braces are required when
    parameter is a positional parameter with more than one digit,  or  when
    parameter  is followed by a character which is not to be interpreted as
    part of its name.  The parameter is  a  shell  parameter  as  described
    above PARAMETERS) or an array reference (Arrays).
```

Donde `${var1}` es la forma más básica de expansión del parámetro `var1`. Pero, por así decirlo `${var1}` protege a la variable `var1`.
Osea, producen lo mismo, son equivalentes, pero no son exactamente son lo mismo. En la primera se realizó un *parameter expansion* con sus potenciales características, en el segundo caso, únicamente se sustituyó el valor de la variable `var1`.
Sin embargo, en toda esa sección hay instrucciones de las propiedades que tiene.

Un ejemplo es este. Es referente a asignar un valor por defecto a una variable.

```
#!/bin/bash 
unset v
echo "La variable v no existe: $v"

v=${v:=hola}  # Ahora, si no existe entonces adquiere el valor por defecto "hola"
echo "La variable v ya existe: $v"

v=${v:=adios}  # Pero si la intentas modificar de esta manera, estando ya definida, no podras.
echo "La variable v en lugar de ser 'adios' es: $v"
```

Dando como resultado:

```
$ ./prueba
La variable v no existe:
La variable v ya existe: hola
La variable v en lugar de ser 'adios' es: hola
```

Otro uso muy comun de la expansion es con *arrays*. Por ejemplo.

```
$ declare -a array1=( valor1 valor2 valor3 )
$ echo ${array1[@]}  # Expande los valores.
valor1 valor2 valor3
$ echo ${#array1[@]} # Muestra el tamano
3
$ echo ${!array1[@]} # Muestra las keys
0 1 2
```

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, es un hecho que me siento más cómodo con el $(comando) por la facilidad de uso en los meta caracteres pero era una duda molesta, en cuanto al ${} desconocia su potencial para la manipulación de dicha variable.

Answer (score 0):

el uso de `$(command)` vs `` `comand` `` es solo por cuestiones de facilidad ya que el uso de `` `command` `` es un poco dificil para los teclados en espa;ol.

y la sixtasis `$(command)` es mucho mas practica y simple.
fuera de que esta presente en muchos mas lenguajes `costumbres`.

meintras  `${var}` vs `$var` son exatamente  iguales en ciertos casos
el uso de los corchetes es para resolver la ambigüedad en las expresiones:

```
var="carro"
echo "${var}ceria"
```

lo que esta dentro de los corchetes se tomara como variable y el resto como texto

mientras que:

```
var="carro"
echo "$varceria"
```

no imprimira nada ya que tomara toda la palabra como nombre de variable.

el uso mas frequente de la primera se debe a esto

esto no esta solo presente en bash, si no que en muchos lenguajes de programacion se utiliza

una referencia
[stackoverflow US](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135451/what-is-the-difference-between-var-var-and-var-in-the-bash-shell)

Comment: Sin duda me quedo con el $() y el ${}, gracias!